# How get all matching positions in a string?

Tags: sql, postgresql, pattern-matching, unnest

I have a column `flag_acumu` in a table in PostgreSQL with values like:

```
'SSNSSNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNSNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN'
```

I need to show all positions with an 'S'. With this code, I only get the first such position, but not the later ones.

```
SELECT codn_conce, flag_acumu, position('S' IN flag_acumu) AS the_pos 
FROM dh12 
WHERE position('S' IN flag_acumu) != 0 
ORDER BY the_pos ASC;
```

How to get all of them?

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  You have essentially said:  "I am using the `position()` function as documented; it is returning the correct results, and I don't like them."

Comment: This might be helpful: https://bytes.com/topic/postgresql/answers/798130-find-position-character-string

Comment: Please be more explicit about what your issue is. Please describe precisely what output you are expecting, which would most certainly require you to provide sample data and sample output.

Answer (score 3):

In Postgres **9.4** or later you can conveniently use `unnest()` in combination with `WITH ORDINALITY`:

```
SELECT *
FROM   dh12 d
JOIN   unnest(string_to_array(d.flag_acumu, NULL))
          WITH ORDINALITY u(elem, the_pos) ON u.elem = 'S'
WHERE  d.flag_acumu LIKE '%S%'  -- optional, see below
ORDER  BY d.codn_conce, u.the_pos;
```

This returns one row per match.
`WHERE  d.flag_acumu LIKE '%S%'` is optional to quickly eliminate source rows without any matches. Pays if there are more than a few such rows.

Detailed explanation and alternatives for older versions:

- [PostgreSQL unnest() with element number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760419/postgresql-unnest-with-element-number/8767450#8767450)

Answer (score 2):

Since you didn't specify your needs to a point in which one could answer properly, I'm going with my assumption that you want a list of positions of occurence of a substring (can be more than 1 character long).

Here's the function to do that using:

- `FOR .. LOOP` control structure,
- function `substr(text, int, int)`.

---

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_all_positions_of_substring(text, text)
RETURNS text
STABLE
STRICT
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
DECLARE
  output_text TEXT := '';
BEGIN

FOR i IN 1..length($1)
LOOP
  IF substr($1, i, length($2)) = $2 THEN
    output_text := CONCAT(output_text, ';', i);
  END IF;
END LOOP;

-- Remove first semicolon
output_text := substr(output_text, 2, length(output_text));

RETURN output_text;
END;
$$;
```

Sample call and output

```
postgres=# select * from get_all_positions_of_substring('soklesocmxsoso','so');
 get_all_positions_of_substring
--------------------------------
 1;6;11;13
```

Answer (score 0):

This works too. And a bit faster I think.

```
create or replace function findAllposition(_pat varchar, _tar varchar) 
returns int[] as
$body$
declare _poslist int[]; _pos int;
begin

_pos := position(_pat in _tar);
while (_pos>0)
loop

    if array_length(_poslist,1) is null then
        _poslist := _poslist || (_pos);
    else
        _poslist := _poslist || (_pos + _poslist[array_length(_poslist,1)] + 1);
    end if;

    _tar := substr(_tar, _pos + 1, length(_tar));
    _pos := position(_pat in _tar);

end loop;
return _poslist;

end;
$body$
language plpgsql;
```

Will return a position list which is an int array.

```
{position1, position2, position3, etc.}
```