# Postgres Convert Text array to Int array

Tags: arrays, postgresql

In order to use Unnest function I want convert a list to array.

This is my list of type text. It's an output of this function ([How get all positions in a field in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34495881/how-get-all-positions-in-a-field-in-postgresql)):

```
108,109,110,114,115,116,117,156,157,200,201,205
```

I convert to array with

```
array[108,109,110,114,115,116,117,156,157,200,201,205]
```

result is type text[]:

```
"{"108,109,110,114,115,116,117,156,157,200,201,205"}"
```

With this kind of array unnest function doesn't work so I think I want convert to array of Int

Thanks

Comment: `select concat('{','108,109,110,114,115,116,117,156,157,200,201,205','}')::int[];` [Array Value Input](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html#ARRAYS-INPUT)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with the_data(str) as (
    select '108,109,110,114,115,116,117,156,157,200,201,205'::text
)

select elem
from the_data,
unnest(string_to_array(str, ',')) elem;

 elem 
------
 108
 109
 110
 114
 115
 116
 117
 156
 157
 200
 201
 205
(12 rows)
```

Comment: Alter column from `text[]` to `integer[]`.
Refer to https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/331422/279664

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understand, you need this  (no  necessary  convert to `INT`):

```
select unnest( string_to_array('108,109,110,114,115,116,117,156,157,200,201,205', ',' ) )
```